# Kubernetes + ingress-nginx - two apps, one of which in / path

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have two apps on a Kubernetes cluster which need to be exposed. One is a OAuth2 based authenticator, the other is the client app using it.
I would like to have the client app on `test.mydomain.com` and the authenticator on `test.mydomain.com/auth`

I tried building the following ingress in Kubernetes:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTP"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "20m"
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
        - path: /auth
          backend:
            serviceName: authenticator-service
            servicePort: 8080
        - path: /
          backend:
            serviceName: app-service
            servicePort: 8080
```

For some reason, I can't get it to work, and whenever I try and hit `test.mydomain.com/auth` I end up hitting the main `app-service`. Am I doing something completely wrong? Is what I want to do even possible?

Comment: Not sure what version of kubernetes version you're on, but you might want to look at the pathtype: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#examples

Comment: What is says is that the prefix `/` matches ALL path types. What I'm not sure is, if there's a way to match ALL paths except /auth

Comment: @Nick Melis Try to add `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /` or `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1` to your annotations and check if it works as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  name: my-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: app-service
          servicePort: 8080
      - path: /auth/(.*)
        backend: 
          serviceName: authenticator-service
          servicePort: 8080
```